# SUMIFS using comma delimited string as argument

Tags: excel

I have a SUMIFS that looks like this

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('EMPLOYEES'!J:J,'Collections Test'!B:B,AE15,'EMPLOYEES'!F:F,{"00865","00866","00870","16411","16419","00978","10017","90185","90024","00069"},'EMPLOYEES'!C:C,{"STAFF"}))
```

I want to run a query that sets the cell "A2" value to:

```
 "00865","00866","00870","16411","16419","00978","10017","90185","90024","00069"
```

Then reference A2 in my formula like:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('EMPLOYEES'!J:J,'Collections Test'!B:B,AE15,'EMPLOYEES'!F:F,{A2},'EMPLOYEES'!C:C,{"STAFF"}))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible. Are the employee numbers always 5 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the employee numbers are always 5 digits, this will work:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('EMPLOYEES'!J:J,'Collections Test'!B:B,AE15,'EMPLOYEES'!F:F,MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(LEN(A2)+1)/8))*8-6,5),'EMPLOYEES'!C:C,"STAFF"))`

If the employee numbers are not always 5 digits, it will be a little more complicated:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('EMPLOYEES'!J:J,'Collections Test'!B:B,AE15,'EMPLOYEES'!F:F,MID(A2,SMALL(IFERROR(IF(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)+1))-1,1)=",",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))-1),0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1)))+2,SMALL(IFERROR(IF(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)+1))-1,1)=",",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))-1),LEN(A2)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1)))-SMALL(IFERROR(IF(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)+1))-1,1)=",",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))-1),0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1)))-3),'EMPLOYEES'!C:C,"STAFF"))`